# Why is not deal_price updating in the code?

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php 

include('db/dbcon.php');

$get_id=$_GET['id'];

$deal_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqli, $_POST['deal_price']);
mysqli_query($sqli, "UPDATE product_detail 
                     SET deal_price = '$deal_price' 
                     WHERE id = '$get_id' ")
                or die(mysqli_error());
echo "<script>alert('Successfully Updated'); window.location='sales_rep?status=1.php'</script>";

?>
```

Comment: Please do *some* validation at least. A little [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) won't do too much harm.

Comment: So much sql injection in this code.... beofre solving anything, fix that..

Comment: As @Fred-ii- would say, please show us your form too.

Comment: pls how do i go about with the validation?

Comment: @edrees by reading the links I provided in my comment.

Comment: ok I will paste the form

Comment: `window.location='sales_rep?status=1.php'` I dont think that `.php` should be there probably should be `window.location='sales_rep.php?status=1'`

Comment: *..ok I will paste the form* ~ Still Waiting.

Comment: This code just has to be putting errors into the _PHP Error log_ Have you looked that that. OR add these 2 line right after the `<?php` to show errors on the page `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: *"ok I will paste the form – edrees 15 mins ago"*  - That was 15 mins. ago; where's the notorious form everyone's waiting for? I'm not going to stick around here for more than 5 mins. Time, like oil, is a valued commodity.

Comment: @RiggsFolly They're prolly going to come back and tell us: *"Undefined index, blah blah blah"* and prolly doing a "facepalm" right.... about....... *now*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Even if it is there I can see at least one syntax error that should fail a compile

Comment: @RiggsFolly I see it too ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- But I am like you _Desperately seeking susan_ Or is that _the promised land_ NO _The promised form_

Comment: @RiggsFolly [*He did say it best...*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WZbxYGy3As)

Comment: well, it's been a slice, let's do it twice. I'm outta here. As Bugs would say.... *"NNnnnext!"*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1) You should check first the variable which you are using exist or not

2) Also pass `$sqli` in `mysqli_error();`

```
<?php

include('db/dbcon.php');
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
  $get_id = $_GET['id'];
  $deal_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqli, $_POST['deal_price']);
  mysqli_query($sqli, "UPDATE product_detail SET deal_price = '$deal_price' WHERE id = '$get_id' ")or die(mysqli_error($sqli));
  echo "<script>alert('Successfully Updated'); window.location='sales_rep?status=1.php'</script>";
} else {
  echo "no id";
}
?>
```